# pass username and password from html to another file

Tags: html, authentication, http, server

I am building a web application with some other people and I am in charge to do the database. I have been looking for a while now and I am looking for a way to pass the input that was inputted in an html file which i didn't create (through a form) into another python file where I am using sqlite in order to handle input.
What is the best way to redirect this input to the other file?

Chat gpt told me to user the form action '/submit_form' and the method 'post'. I don't know what these do but I've included it in the code.

I am putting the code for this form below.

Very simply, I am trying to handle the input from this form in the HTML file, in another python file but I am unsure how to 'pass' it to the other file.

```html
        <form action="/submit_form" method="post">
            <h1>Sign up | Log in</h1>
            <div class="input-box">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Username" required>
                <i class='bx bx-user'></i>
            </div>
            <div class="input-box">
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password" required>
                <i class='bx bx-lock'></i>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn">Sign up</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn">Log in</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: This is a reasonable way to handle it. You have to make sure that your python HTTP server listens to the `/submit_form` endpoint. If you have no idea what I just said, learn something like Flask or Django first.